# How to stop a slider from changing its position according to the height of a div?

Tags: html, css, slider, height

```js
let Container = document.getElementById("Container1");
let slider = document.getElementById("slider1");

Container.setAttribute("style", "height: " + slider.value + "px");

slider.oninput = function() {
  Container.setAttribute("style", "height: " + this.value + "px");
};
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

#Container1 {
  width: 160px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#slider1 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: black;
  width: 90px;
  height: 1px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateX(0.5cm) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="Container1"></div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="90" id="slider1" />
</div>
```

Here, it seems like the slider is changing its position with the height of the div element beside it. Why is this happening? How to stop it? On my attempt, I tried setting `.container {height: 90px;}` and the original problem got fixed but something strange happens. Why does that happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

I put height on the main div so all content remains in the static div.

and `transform: translateY(-50%) translateY(1.2cm)` transform Y to 1.2cm

`align-items: start;` so items are positioned at the beginning of the container

```js
let Container = document.getElementById("Container1");
let slider = document.getElementById("slider1");

Container.setAttribute("style", "height: " + slider.value + "px");

slider.oninput = function() {
  Container.setAttribute("style", "height: " + this.value + "px");
};
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: start;
    height: 90px;
}

#Container1 {
  width: 160px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#slider1 {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: black;
    width: 90px;
    height: 1px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateX(0.5cm) translateY(-50%) translateY(1.2cm) rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="Container1"></div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="90" id="slider1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let Container = document.getElementById("Container1");
let slider = document.getElementById("slider1");

Container.setAttribute("style", "height: " + slider.value + "px");

slider.oninput = function() {
  Container.setAttribute("style", "height: " + this.value + "px");
};
```

The slider changes the height of the Container, because you set the Containers height attribute to be the slider value. Remove these javascript lines and the slider will stop changing the height of the container.

The javascript code listens to the input on the slider and when the slider is moved, the Containers height attribute will be set to `this.value`. In this case `this` refers to the slider.

Comment: The slider was meant for changing the height of the Container, the moving position was unintended. I want to remove that, how do I do it? Your answer disregards the motive for which the slider is set.